# Reading with vector::data()[] seems faster than vector[]

Tags: c++, performance, vector

I did this small console test using Visual Studio 2019 fully updated, and executing this in release mode using Ctrl-F5.

```
    // 1. I generate a random vector
    std::vector<int> vectorVal;
    for (int i=0; i!=32; ++i)
    {
        vectorVal.push_back(i-3);
    }

    // 2. Then I perform some reads
    int uselessValue = 0;
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now(); // I take initial time
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j!=32; ++j)
        {
            // uselessValue += (vectorVal.data()[j]? +1 : -1); // Faster!!!!
            uselessValue += (vectorVal[j]? +1 : -1); // Slower
        }
    }
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now(); // and end time

    // 3. Last, I show the time it needed to perform the operations
    std::cout<<"Vector "<<uselessValue<<": \t"<<duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end-start).count()<<" nanoseconds.\n"<<std::endl;
```

If you execute this, the result are around 80000 nanoseconds on my computer. However, if you use the "Faster" line instead the "Slower" one, the result is 100 nanoseconds.

I tried to debug this to see what's happening. Basically it should do the same, access to a basic C array, but it seems much faster with the `vectorVal::data()[]`. I'm quite sure I'm doing something wrong in my testing, but I fail to realize what's wrong.

Why does seem faster using `vector::data()[]` than `vector[]` to access its content?

Here's the full source code:

```
    const int num = 10000;

{
    std::vector<int> vectorVal;
    for (int i=0; i!=32; ++i)
    {
        vectorVal.push_back(i-3);
    }
    int uselessValue = 0;
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    int* data = vectorVal.data();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j!=32; ++j)
        {
            uselessValue += (vectorVal.data()[j]? +1 : -1);
        }
    }
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout<<"Vector-data"<<uselessValue<<": \t"<<duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end-start).count()<<" nanoseconds.\n"<<std::endl;
}

{
    std::vector<int> vectorVal;
    for (int i=0; i!=32; ++i)
    {
        vectorVal.push_back(i-3);
    }


    int uselessValue = 0;
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; ++i)
    {
        for (int j=0; j!=32; ++j)
        {
            uselessValue += (vectorVal[j]? +1 : -1);
        }
    }
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    std::cout<<"Vector "<<uselessValue<<": \t"<<duration_cast<nanoseconds>(end-start).count()<<" nanoseconds.\n"<<std::endl;
}
```

I've uploaded the Visual Studio 2019 project solution [here](https://easyupload.io/yof8lr), you may download it and test directly. Maybe I'm failing with my settings.

Comment: How often did you repeat your trial? In general, to make a fair comparison is not that easy. Just to compile and run each version once is not reliable. Maybe, try this on [Quick Bench](https://quick-bench.com/).

Comment: A lot! In fact, I was testing both versions in the same run

Comment: Using the Quick Bench, Clang 13, I have similar results. However VS2019 uses it's own compiler. Could be a Microsoft Compiler or settings fault?

Comment: _I was testing both versions in the same run_ Please, [edit] your MCVE and show the loops with which you tested. - I mean, accessing the same array a 2nd time is probably unfair. So, you should at least allocate new data for each run.

Comment: Done, I also tried in different order, but I had same result.

Comment: Similar code compiles to [exactly the same assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/cz5TnK78K) if optimization is enabled. Check the assembly code that VS generates.

Comment: They do produce quite different [disassembly](https://godbolt.org/z/K847Mabnv)

Answer (score 1):

Your compiler must be set to debug mode, rather than release/optimized mode.  The effect of this is that `vector::data()[i]` is faster than `vector[i]` because the latter will likely check `i < vector::size()` in a debug build for safety, while a release mode with optimization enabled will generate identical code for both.

Performance testing must always be done with optimized release builds, because that's the type of build you'd run whenever you care about performance in a real application.

Comment: I'm quite sure I'm compiling in release mode. Under project settings->c++->optimization, I have enabled mode /O2 (speed). Executing standalone .exe file has the same effect.

Comment: @JuanJuezSarmiento You also need to make sure you aren't using debug libraries.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/crt-library-features?view=msvc-170 and review your `/MT` or `/MD` settings.

Comment: I've edited the post, adding a link to download my VS2019 solution, I you want to test it quickly

Comment: Tried the /MD and /MT settings, it produces same result. About debug libraries, I think I'm not using them. It's an empty new project with that code and the array/chrono include

Comment: Which of the four build types in your configuration are you running?

Comment: The release code does indeed exhibit different behaviour between the two sources: https://godbolt.org/z/K847Mabnv

Comment: @AlanBirtles: Thanks, it looks like MSVC is failing to optimize properly in this more complex code, even though it can optimize properly in simpler cases.